# Can you get the following asymptotics?

Tags: asymptotics

Consider
$$
e^{N/d}\frac{d}{2N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left(\frac{d}{N}\right)^nn!
$$
I know its asyptotics when $d<e$ but I haven't suceeded for $d\geq e$. Can you do better and work out its big $N$ asymptotics for $d\geq e$?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Alex I cannot get the big $N$asymptotics for $d\geq e$.

Comment: Have you tried exploiting $$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\alpha^n n! = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(\alpha x)^n = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(\alpha x)^N-1}{\alpha x-1}e^{-x}\,dx=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^N-1}{z-1}e^{-z/\alpha}\,dz$$ and Laplace method?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have precisely come from the last equation on the right. I am not very familiar with Laplace and saddles unfortunately...

Comment: Then try this simple approach: on the interval $(0,1)$ we have $e^{-z/\alpha}\leq 1$, hence such interval contributes to the global integral by at most $H_N\sim\log(N)$. On the interval $(1,+\infty)$, the integral is very close to $\int_{1}^{+\infty}z^{N-1}e^{-z/\alpha}\,dz$ and $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{N-1}e^{-z/\alpha}\,dz$$ is easy to compute through the $\Gamma$ function.